# react apollo - clear data object before refetch

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

When using `refetch` of `useQuery` hook the `data` object is still defined. And when using infinite scrolling, only the first page will be refetched.

Is it possible to clear the `data` object before calling the `refech` so that we can start fresh?

```
const { data, loading, error, fetchMore, refetch } = useQuery(GET_ALL_ITEMS, {variables});
getNextPage = async () => { // merges results for infinite scrolling
    await fetchMore({ variables, 
        updateQuery: (previousResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
            const oldEntries = previousResult.items;
            const newEntries = fetchMoreResult.items;
            fetchMoreResult.items = [...oldEntries, ...newEntries];
            return fetchMoreResult;
        },
    )
}
```

Can I do something like `refresh = () => { data = null; refetch(); }` but without directly mutating state?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to clear `data` but found a different approach in [Apollo Client v3 docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#inspecting-loading-states).

Basically it's to ignore loaded `data` when `loading` or in case of `error`:

```js
const { data: loadedData, loading, error, fetchMore, refetch } = useQuery(
  GET_ALL_ITEMS, 
  {
    variables,
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true, // important for adequate loading state
  }
);

const data = (loading || error) ? undefined : loadedData;
```

**Note**, that in order to make `loading` work for refetch, you need to pass `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true` option.

It's also possible to get `networkStatus` from `useQuery` result and check it like this:

```
networkStatus === NetworkStatus.refetch
```

but it seems to work for me with `loading` and `error` only.

Comment: Consider an infinite scroll paginated list. Refetch will update the items for the first page but, if there are more pages, it will show old values. I don't need those pages to update automatically. But it would be nice to have them not show up at all, so that we can fetch them again when scrolled. That's why I need a way to clear the whole data object.